# How to connect from RStudio to a local git repository

Tags: r, git, repository, rstudio

I definitely have a lack in my understandind and try to fill this gap!
I am completely new to git local on my machine. I have some experience using github. But here I want to use a version control on my local machine. But after researching a while I get stuck now!

**What I want**
I want a version control on my local machine for my R projects only for me with no need to access from anywhere but from this local machine.

**What I have so far**

1. I have RStudio installed (Windows)
2. I have installed git bash and git desktop
3. I have set up git server on local my local machine (Windows tutorial) https://medium.com/@piteryo7/how-to-set-up-git-server-on-local-network-windows-tutorial-7ec5cd2df3b1
4. My first git is cloned and located `C:/Users/Public/Git_Server/myfirst.git`
5. I have started a new project in RStudio and named it `xxx` like here:
   [image]
6. Then in the Terminal of Rstudio I give in the following command:
   [image]

**I do not understand how to connect my new project with my local repository, so that I can commit and push and pull!**

Any direction will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hej TarJae. There is no need for push and pull in case of only local git. Simply commit your changes and they will be tracked.

Comment: @stefan Thank you for your reply that is very helpful. How can I 'synchronize' my project xxx with myfirst.git repository.  So for next project I would create next repository for example mysecond.git. I just don't understand if I commit in which repository it is commited.  I am sure I miss something very simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hm. When I use git I simply use the default `.git` repository added to the RStudio project folder, so I don't (have to) care about that. Doing so I could add the files I want to commit via "git add xxx" and then commit via "git commit --message ...". git (or RStudio) will keep track of the rest.

Comment: @stefan Hurray. Thanks to stefan I got my first commit on my local repository. You are my hero stefan!

Comment: :D You are welcome, TarJae. Always glad to help.